# "consensus over state" vs. "consensus over events"?

Tags: blockchain, proof-of-stake, consensus

Does someone know what is difference between "**consensus over state**" and "**consensus over events**" ?

I found just title of a reference i.e. "`Ian Grigg, blog post “The Message is the Medium,” 2017`."

However, I could not find any pdf, paper or article with this title. Just there is a very general and unclear information on this topic of consensus in "[EOS - An Introduction](https://eos.io/documents/EOS_An_Introduction.pdf)". For example, it is not clear to me what does "**Restart**" mean in this document?

Is there better and more clear reference on this this type of **consensus**?

Comment: This looks like the article you're looking for https://steemit.com/eos/@iang/the-message-is-the-medium